# How to Disable Enum Check In Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, database-migration

I want to add another new enum column in the table, but not able to migrate, as it says column already exists.

**Migration**

```php
class DesignationColumnNullableInUserTable extends Migration
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::getDoctrineSchemaManager()
        ->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
        Type::addType('enum', \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\StringType::class);
    }

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->enum('designation', ['Lawyer', 'Freelancer', 
                'Corporate secretary', 'Immigration Consultant'])
             ->nullable()->change();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropIfExists('designation');
        });
    }
}
```

I have also made some changes in another migration with a foreign key.

```php
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::getDoctrineSchemaManager()
    ->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
```

How can I fix this issue for the enum check?

Comment: Caution: Save DB backup before any action. Tried resetting migrations and deleting all tables from DB? Maybe reset doesn't delete all tables.

Comment: Dbal dont support enum modify.. im suggesting to you to use integer instead of enum. 1 = lawyer, 2 = freelancer ..etc... easier to modify in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel does not support modifying enum columns, so instead use a raw statement:

```
public function up() {
    DB::statement("ALTER TABLE users MODIFY COLUMN designation ENUM('Lawyer', 'Freelancer', 'Corporate secretary', 'Immigration Consultant')");
}
```

For MySQL you should be able to use the following:

```
// up
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE users CHANGE designation designation ENUM('Lawyer', 'Freelancer', 'Corporate secretary', 'Immigration Consultant')");
```

Comment: Which type of database are you running? MySQL, SQLite, MSSQL?

Comment: i am using mysql image ie. Adminer 4.6.3 4.7.1 (docker) in my project.